# How do I add a Key/Value in JSON with Python?

Tags: python, json

This may sound like an average question, but I haven't found a good answer to what I am trying to do.

Take d.json:

```
{"SDA":{"Info":{"Description":"Anti Advertisment Bot, Blocks invites extensively.","Download Link":"http://sda.khionu.net/docs/, http://sda.khionu.net/docs/"}}, "Unit 02":{"Info":{"Description":"Server logging bot, c!serverlogs 'server name here if spaces' <# 1-9999>","Download Link":"https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=222881716606468096&scope=bot&permissions=32768"}}}
```

I'm trying to add this to it, separated by commas:

```
{'Ctest': {'Info': {'Description': 'Hi', 'Download Link': 'Sure'}}}
```

I tried multiple ways to do it, but none works. Here's my current code

```
a = d[toolname] = {str(toolname):{"Info":{"Description": tooldesc, "Download Link": toollink}}}
f.write(str(a))
f.close()
return jsonify(a), 201
```

My whole goal is to write

```
{'Ctest': {'Info': {'Description': 'Hi', 'Download Link': 'Sure'}}}
```

to d.json like this

```
{"SDA":{"Info":{"Description":"Anti Advertisment Bot, Blocks invites extensively.","Download Link":"http://sda.khionu.net/docs/, http://sda.khionu.net/docs/"}}, "Unit 02":{"Info":{"Description":"Server logging bot, c!serverlogs 'server name here if spaces' <# 1-9999>","Download Link":"https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=222881716606468096&scope=bot&permissions=32768"}}, {'Ctest': {'Info': {'Description': 'Hi', 'Download Link': 'Sure'}}}
```

Comment: You haven't found a good reference on parsing JSON and making a Python dictionary?

Comment: You need to use square brackets `[` in JSON to denote an array of values - curly braces `{` are for objects (named properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**json module**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) for that, code below shall give you the clue:

```
import json
data = json.load('path_to_json_file')
data['key'] = 'value'
json.dump('path_to_json_file', data)
```

Comment: In case you have json in format of {'attributes' : [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2'}]}
and you want to add a key value pair use 
data['attributes'][0]['key3'] = 'value3' to get  {'attributes' : [{'key1':'value1','key2':'value2','key3':'value3'}]}

otherwise, you will get an error in this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
jsonObject['Ctest'] = {'Info': {'Description': 'Hi', 'Download Link': 'Sure'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to franklinsijo, I found an answer, and it is a duplicate, surprise surprise.

I reformatted the code to this:

```
        a = d[toolname] = {toolname:{"Info":{"Description": tooldesc, "Download Link": toollink}}}
        with open('data1.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(d))
            f.close()
        return jsonify(a), 201
```

Thanks for answering guys, I'll flag as a duplicate of his question.